# Data member of base class gives garbage value when used in derived class

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, radix

In this program, whenever I try to access the data member of the base class 'radius' in the derived class, the value of the radius becomes a garbage value. What am I doing wrong? How do I solve this problem?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
class circle{
    public:
        int radius, circrea;
        void getRadius(){
            cout<<"Enter radius: "<<endl;
            cin>>radius;
            }
        void area(){
            circrea = 3.14*radius*radius;
            }
        void display(){
            cout<<"Area of circle is: "<<circrea<<endl;
            }

};
class cylinder: public circle{
    public:
        int height, cylrea;
        void getHeight(){
            cout<<"Enter height: "<<endl;
            cin>>height;
            }
        void area(){
            cylrea = 2 * 3.14 * radius * (radius + height);
            }
        void display(){
            cout<<"Area of cylinder is: "<<cylrea<<endl;
            }
};
int main(){
    circle c;
    cylinder c1;
    c.getRadius();
    c.area();
    c.display();
    c1.getHeight();
    c1.area();
    c1.display();
}
```

Comment: you never call `c1.getRadius()` so `radius` is uninitialised?

Comment: I want to use the same value of 'radius' that I had entered in the base class, how do I do that? Thanks

Comment: `c` and `c1` are completely unrelated objects you can't use the members of one in the other, just call all the base class methods on `c1`

Comment: So, how do I inherit the radius from the base class to the derived class? Are there other ways than calling the getRadius twice? Thanks

Comment: It *is* inherited. `c1` has its *own* radius, inherited from class `circle` , that was never initialized, as mentioned before. `c` is an *instance* of a `circle`, `c1` is a completely independent *instance* of a `cylinder` . Honestly, I don't see why having `c` in this program gets you at all. You should have a single `cylinder`, then get its radius *and* height, etc,

Comment: Looks like you need to spend some time thinking about the difference between types (classes) and values (objects).